# How default assignment operator works in struct?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a structure in C++ containing a name and a number, e.g.

```
struct person {

char name[20];

int ssn;

};
```

Suppose I declare two `person` variables:

```
person a;

person b;
```

where `a.name = "George"`, `a.ssn = 1`, and `b.name = "Fred"` and `b.ssn = 2`.

Suppose later in the code

```
a = b;

printf("%s %d\n",a.name, a.ssn);
```

Comment: Is there a question somewhere in there?

Comment: Skydoor appears to believe that SO is a replacement for reading books, or even thinking. 129 questions - zero answers.

Comment: Speaking of books, may I point you to http://www.amazon.com/Primer-Plus-5th-Stephen-Prata/dp/0672326973/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1269107822&sr=8-1

Comment: @wheaties Why would you want to do that? Why not point them at something useful, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The default assignment operator does a member-wise recursive assignment of each member.

Answer (score 10):

The default assignment operator in C++ uses [Memberwise Assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0c54csc(VS.80).aspx) to copy the values.  That is it effectively assigns all members to each other.  In this case that would cause b to have the same values as a.

For example

```
a = b;
printf("%s\n", b.name); // Prints: George
b.name[0]='T';
printf("%s\n", a.Name); // Prints George
printf("%s\n", b.name); // Prints Teorge
```